# Bluemix Iot Foudation,how to achieve data visiulization?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

I’m using the Bluemix Iot service and I have successfully make the device connect to both the bluemix and quickstart. Quickstart can achieve data visualization, but a web page can just display one device.
Is the quickstart  a kind of service which deploy in the Bluemix? if I want to design a webpage to show visualization of multiple devices, can I deploy any kind of service to achieve this function in Bluemix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could design a webpage to show visualization of multiple devices.  To do this, you should create an IoT platform service and register your devices rather than using Quickstart.

See this [visualization recipe](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/visualizing-your-data/) for details.   There is sample code available in [GitHub.](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-visualization/)

Comment: Thank you very much,you are so helpful.